# On disks divided into $n$ parts of equal area and their transformations via Riemann mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, area, curves

Suppose that we divide some disk into $n$ parts of equal area in such a way that we choose some point $A_1$ on the circle and then find $(n-1)$ points $A_2,...A_n$ on the circle in such a way that the lines $A_1A_2,...,A_1A_n$ divide the disk into $n$ parts of equal area.

Now take some closed convex set $C$ which is not a disk and transform the disk with  bijective holomorphic mapping onto $C$.

Now generally the lines $A_1A_2,...A_1A_n$ will be transformed into curves $C_1C_2,...C_1C_n$.

> Does there exist $C$ such that curves $C_1C_2,...,C_1C_n$ divide $C$ into $n$ parts of equal area no matter where the position of $A_1$ is?

Comment: I have had a look at your profile, and seen the questions you asked. As none is checked (the green check sign that you surely have seen), I have an important advise to give you: you have to check one of the answers that has been given to your question (under the condition of course that it brings a satisfactory answer...). I don't say this for me, I have a sufficiently high ranking... and when you have doubts, choose the low rank answerers for promoting them.

Comment: @JeanMarie But only 2 out of my 7 questions are answered?

Comment: I hadn't noticed...

Comment: @JeanMarie No problem. Take it easy.

Comment: This issue of transformations that preserve areas is met in catography for example (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalEqual-AreaProjection.html), (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection). But I don't know functions Z=f(z) and (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertAzimuthalEqual-AreaProjection.html) and a deep study (http://cartography.oregonstate.edu/pdf/2014_Savric_Jenny_ANewPseudocylindricalEqual-areaProjection.pdf).